# Amazon FPS Integration with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-fps

Apparently the Amazon Flexible Payments Service is similar to Google Checkout (which I have been able to implement). However I'm getting lost in the Amazon documentation. I have even downloaded the C# SDK and it's still not clear what I need to do.

I was wondering if anyone else could share how they did it. Preferably using WSDL. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still working out how to do it, since their documentation is about as organized as an orangutan with a paintbrush, but it seems like there are generally two actions that need to happen: 1) Initiate the request, including the amount, etc.  The result of this will be an authorized token from the user confirming their intent to purchase 2) Using this token, you can complete the transfer and then redirect your application as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Lol I'm with you on the documentation. Although PayPal's is arguably worse. I think the bit which confuses me is that you click on the Developers tab and FPS is the only option. However under the Business tab. If you navigate to the ecommerce part then you find what you really want.